# A value is NaN online but works as a number locally in Javascript

Tags: javascript, tomcat, heroku

I have a Javascript code working perfectly locally, but once deployed online with Heroku, gives me a NaN error for a numeric value, taken from the object `propertyService`. This is the code:

```
 $.get(contextPath + "get-total-amount-from-search-box", {
    from: dateFrom,
    to: dateTo,
    idproperty: idproperty,
    guests: guests
    },
    function(propertyService){
        if(propertyService){
        pricePreview.removeAttribute("hidden");
        var totalAmount = parseFloat(propertyService.totalAmount);

        console.log("Total amount isNaN: " + isNaN(totalAmount));

        if(propertyService.serviceCharge){
            totalAmount = totalAmount + parseFloat(propertyService.serviceCharge);
            serviceChargePreview.innerHTML = serviceChargeText + ": " + Math.round(propertyService.serviceCharge).toLocaleString(language) + " " + currency;
        }
        totalAmountPreview.innerHTML  = totalAmountText + ": " + Math.round(totalAmount).toLocaleString(language) + " " + currency;
        } else {
            pricePreview.setAttribute("hidden", true);
        }
    }
 );
```

`isNaN(totalAmount)` Locally returns false and online true. I can't figure out, why is behaving differently online than locally.

The web server is Tomcat, and the app from which comes the object `propertyService` is developed in Java, with the Spring framework using Thymeleaf as template engine.

Comment: Have you checked **propertyService.totalAmount** before parsing it to a float?

Comment: Make sure if isNaN is getting the same value in both instances, maybe you are getting a valid number from the service when deployed.

Comment: **propertyService.totalAmount** locally before parsing it to a float gives false to isNaN, but online gives true. What I don't understand, is why online changes the result. Instead of using **parseFloat(propertyService.serviceCharge)** I have tried using **Number(proprtyService.serviceCharge)**, with the same result.

Comment: The problem was with the **contextPath** variable. The app runs with different domains, and the request needs to be done, to an specific domain. In fact, it had nothing to do with Javascript.